# About Firebase Rest Api Join Operations

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

We recommend that we keep firebase data in separate collections for children.

```
{
    "users" : {
        "1" : {
            "name" : "David",
            "bio" : "....",
            "avatar" : "https://"
        },
        "9" : {
            "name" : "Alice",
            "bio" : "....",
            "avatar" : "https://"
        }
    },
    "events" : {
        "fm" : {
            "name" : "Firebase 1",
            "date" : "98333"
        }
    },
    "eventAttendees" : {
        "fm" : {
            "1" : "David",
            "9" : "Alice"
        }
    }
}
```

Should I make two GET requests when I want to list the members participating in the event with their avatars and biographies in the layout as above?

I am using Firebase Realtime Database REST API. https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/users.json https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/eventAttendees.json I am combining these two addresses into a list by making a GET request. Am I doing it right? What's the logic in this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'doing it right'? Does it work? If so then it is right.

Comment: I thought of the possibility that there might be another solution without making two GET requests.